# PhD search optimal stopping problem

Tags: phd, remote-work

For personal reasons, I need to spend the majority of my time in city A. I have, however, been offered a STEM PhD (3 years) in neighboring country B, which I can perform remotely as long as I visit somewhat regularly (~1 week per month). It is possible to live with this set-up but I am afraid I may miss out on some of the essential parts of a PhD: connecting with fellow students, getting to know local staff, etc.. I am also aware that working remotely my drain my motivation in the long run. I can pass on the offer and hope that something better comes up in my city A, but I don't find it easy to let go of the opportunity and keep looking.

Am I right for thinking that by not being there much I may miss essential parts of the PhD?

Do you have any advice or experience on what makes a PhD offer "good enough" for you?

Comment: Is it legal for you to live in A most of the time while working in B? Is the university willing to handle things like taxes for an international employee?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that it will be a big problem since you are aware of the issue. You may need to be "especially" social when you are on site having both personal and professional conversations with people (as the pandemic permits). If your advisor is also aware of the issue, and the need for collaborative contacts then it can ease the situation.

You can also try to establish electronic communication with some of those you meet and find it comfortable to discuss things with.

I'd let other factors be decisive in whether this is an opportunity worth taking or not: quality of the program, helpfulness of the advisor, etc.

The world isn't perfect but awareness is a big factor in dealing with it.

---

I taught in a "remote" doctoral program where the students met face to face with each other and faculty only two days a month. But we had very close collaboration via electronic means and it was continuous with lots of contributions by students throughout.